# partition of multidimensional array

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

i am trying to implement following algorithm:
suppose  there is array a[3][3],  my aim is choose some pivot   element,for example a[1][1] and make partition such    that, all element less then a[1][1] must be on left side and above the pivot element, and all greater element on the right   side and below pivot element. for example  consider  following matrix:

```
6 4 3
8 5 2
1 7 9
```

one of the possible partition of it is

```
3 4 6
2 5 7
1 8 9
```

as you see all less element are on the left side and above the pivot called 4. and others on the right side and below the pivot as 8.
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int a[3][3];
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++){
      cin>>a[i][j];
    }
  }

  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  int n=2;
  int m=2;
  int pivot=a[1][1];

  while(  m>i && n>j) {
    while(a[m][n]>pivot)  --m;--n;
    while( a[i][j]<pivot) ++i;++j;

    int t=a[i][j];
    a[i][j]=a[m][n];
    a[m][n]=t;
  }

  for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<3;j++){
      cout<<a[i][j]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but when i enter matrix   above mentioned i got wrong result

```
6  5  3
8  4  2
1  7  9
```

please help me

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: May you forgot parenthesis after `while(a[m][n]>pivot)` and `while( a[i][j]<pivot)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem as stated does not have a general solution. Specifically, there is no guarantee that all of the values less than the initial pivot value will fit to the left of the initial pivot point, nor that all of the values greater than the initial value will fit to the right of the initial pivot point.

You need to relax your requirements so that either the pivot value or the pivot location is allowed to change during the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: yes now i see  it, maybe   pivot element is 1 so it means that such partition will   be impossible,why i wanted   to solve  such   problem is that then if we sort it's rows i think whole  array will be sorted so @Rob in case of i make allowance to move pivot element also when needed how my code will change it's form?

Comment: If the end goal is to sort the array, try this: `std::sort(&a[0][0], &a[3][0]);` If the end goal is to learn how to sort an array, then treat the matrix as a linear array of 9 elements and run [any](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) [sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked if your algorithm is right, but when I see:

`while(a[m][n]>pivot)  --m;--n;`

I think you meant:

`while(a[m][n]>pivot) { --m;--n; }`

Comment: yes @wormsparty  you are right but  problem is not  this. thanks   for reply